# How to display image that i receive as byteArray in url which is one of the response values

Tags: iphone, uiimage, nsdata, synchronous

i receive web service(W/S) response url which contains multiple values like string and image, which is save in NSData. i encode this NSData to string using NSASCIIStringEncoding and parse the string(url) to get individual values from it and save it in NSUserDefaults. My question is on how to retrieve the byte array of the image from the NSUserDefaults to be displayed. In order to do this action should i change the work flow of how i parse the url because this is how i do for all W/S call throughout my app.I send request as

urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can init an UIImage from NSData using

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithData:(NSData *)data
```

Comment: ya that's fine but my problem is how i get the NSData as i receive byte array along with other parameters something like "parameter|value^parameter|value" which i convert to string using NSASCIIStringEncoding and parse it to save the response values to NSUserdefaults. So now the data from which i need to form an image is in NSUserDefaults.

Comment: hi Hanon i got my code straight by converting the byte array in back end to hexa string and appending to rest of the response parameters, n iphone side it didn't give me no problem when i encode the response string to NSASCIIStringEncoding to be parsed.